# ArgoCD deploy app-of-apps to remote cluster

Tags: argocd, gitops

I'm trying to deploy the following app-of-apps `core-services` to my development cluster. I only have one ArgoCD instance in a control cluster where I want to deploy this app-of-apps pattern to my remote clusters. The app-of-apps pattern looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: core-services-development
#  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  destination:
    name: japasp-development-cluster
#    namespace: argocd
  source:
    repoURL: git@gitlab.com:REDACTED/gitops/argocd.git
    path: environments/development/apps/core-services
    targetRevision: main
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      allowEmpty: true
      prune: true
      selfHeal: false
```

My core service app pattern, for example external-dns, looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: external-dns
#  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
  - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: default
  destination:
    name: japasp-development-cluster
    namespace: external-dns
  source:
    repoURL: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    chart: external-dns
    targetRevision: 6.31.6
    plugin:
      name: argocd-vault-plugin-helm
      env:
        - name: HELM_VALUES
          value: |
            replicaCount: 3
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: 10m
                memory: 50Mi
              limits:
                cpu: 10m
                memory: 50Mi
            sources: ['ingress']
            provider: cloudflare
            cloudflare:
              apiToken: <path:kv2/data/cloudflare/api/external-dns#all-domains>
              proxied: false          
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: false
      allowEmpty: false
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```

When I try to sync it I get the following error:

```
The Kubernetes API could not find argoproj.io/Application
for requested resource /cert-manager. Make sure the
"Application" CRD is installed on the destination cluster.
```

Whats wrong here?

I tried to play around with the namespaces but I messed up my control-cluster where these core services are deployed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application` CR is only defined in your "control" cluster but you're trying to deploy an `Application` in your "development" cluster, hence the error.

In an apps-of-apps pattern, you want to deploy the apps definition in the "control" cluster. Only the "final" resources must be deployed in your "development" (or other) cluster.

If `core-services` GitOps directory contains only `Application` definitions, then you want the `destination` of `core-services-development` to be the "control" cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this fixed it partitially. In addition to that I had to rename the ressources for `core-services-development`. E.g. for `external-dns` it's now `external-dns-development`and `external-dns-control`. I thought it would be enough to seperate apps with same name to different destinations, but due to the fact that all apps are managed by one ArgoCD installation, it forces me to have unique name per app.